# How to focus on text box while text is highlighted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to set up a notes UI where the user can type notes while seeing what they highlighted to take notes on.

I have an element with id note which just fades in a textarea where notes can be typed.

My code

```
//on mouse up this function is called            
function note(){
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
  editor = { "startContainer": range.startContainer, "startOffset": range.startOffset, "endContainer": range.endContainer, "endOffset": range.endOffset };     //saves position of highlighted text
  range.setStart(editor.startContainer, editor.startOffset);
  range.setEnd(editor.endContainer, editor.endOffset);
  if (sel != '') {
    //notes element pops up
    $('#note').focus();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
  }
}
```

Without the *removeAllRanges()* and *addRange(range)*, the textarea gets the focus but the text becomes unhighlighted and with it the textarea loses focus but the text stays highlighted.

### **Solution**

In my note menu pop up function I create a span and added a class to it:

```
var $span = $('<span>').addClass('blueHighlight').append(range.extractContents());
range.insertNode($span[0]);
```

I call a function that deletes the span class when the note menu goes away:

```
$('#pages').find('.blueHighlight').each(function(){
     $(this)[0].outerHTML = $(this).text();
});
```

Comment: So basically you are selected some text in the text area and then you want to type in something simultaneously ?

Comment: Yes. I want the user to still see the text highlighted while they type a note for the highlighted text.

Comment: do it how gmail does it , it will look like a text area but the input will start at the place you type , will be tricky but that is the possible soln

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a custom `highlighted` class and surround selected text with a `span` with that class when selected.

Demo:

```js
// Get the selected text's range

function getSelectedTextRange() {
  var selection = window.getSelection();
  if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    var rangeContents = range.cloneContents();
    if (rangeContents.childNodes.length > 0 && rangeContents.childNodes[0].nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
      return range;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

$('#text')
   // On click release, surround highlighted text with a span with highlighted class
  .on('mouseup', function() {
    if (range = getSelectedTextRange()) {
      var $span = $('<span>').addClass('highlighted').append(range.extractContents());
      range.insertNode($span[0]);
      $('#note').focus();
    }
  })
  // On click down, remove all previously highlighted text
  .on('mousedown', function() {
    $(this).find('span').each(function() {
      $(this)[0].outerHTML = $(this).text();
    });
  });
```

```css
#text::selection,
.highlighted {
  color: red;
  background: yellow;
}

#text::-moz-selection,
.highlighted {
  color: red;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text">Highlight me!</div>
<textarea id="note" placeholder="Notes"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks! This really helped me out!